# Connect to a host socket from a docker container

Tags: docker, networking, wsgi

I have the following docker container

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl net-tools netcat nmap
CMD /bin/bash
```

I run it with volume `/tmp` mapped

From host, I created a socket inside `/tmp`. I tested with `ncat` and the connection works from host. However, it does not work from the docker container.

```
ncat -U /tmp/uwsgi.sock
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

How could I achieve this?

Permissions:

```
$ ls -al /tmp/uwsgi.sock
srwxrwxrwx  1 user  wheel  0 Jun 19 23:53 /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

Comment: Can you provide details about how you created the socket and what all commands you ran from the host and from inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

`Ncat: Connection refused.` means peer side has close the connection, so you in container cannot link to it.

One example for you:

**docker host part:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ ncat -lU /tmp/test.sock
hello
world
```

**command to lunch container with another ssh session:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker run -it -v /tmp:/tmp ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
```

**container part:**

```
root@01f724409cec:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl net-tools netcat nmap
root@01f724409cec:/# ncat -U /tmp/test.sock
hello
world
```

You can see on any side when you input `hello`, `world`, another side could see it too.

But if close the unix socket on docker host side:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ ncat -lU /tmp/test.sock
hello
world
^C
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$
```

Then again connect it in container side:

```
root@01f724409cec:/# ncat -U /tmp/test.sock
hello
world
^C
root@01f724409cec:/# ncat -U /tmp/test.sock
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

It will show `Connection refuesd`.

Comment: How does it answer the question? Obviously the listener is running, it didn't close the connection. The problem the OP is facing is that we (me too) get Connection refused anyway.

Comment: Downvoted because, just like @sarimarton, I think your answer doesn't answer the question. And yes, I have the same problem: server listens on socket on host, from the host I can write to the socket, no problem. Same socket bind-mounted into a Docker container, writing to it within the container -> Error 111, Connection refused. :-(

Comment: Quite old thread:) I guess at that time my idea here is my example is fully reproducible. If the example can also run on OP's machine, then surely OP missed some key difference in question. So, can you run my example successfully on your machine? If yes, we need to find the difference between your scenario and my example. If no, then we need to find why my example can work on my machine. Unfortunately, I never get any feedback about above, just a simple word: can't work... while it still get one upvode may means it works for other guy...

Comment: I just try my example with only modification with image name `ubuntu:16.04`, it still works on my side.